# How do I take a screenshot of youtube video with subtitles on with selenium?

Tags: python, selenium

I have been trying to figure out for quite some time how to take a screenshot of a youtube video with subtitles on through selenium.
I have successfully written the program to take just a basic screenshot of a youtube video but thats the only thing i could figure out

Comment: please share the code sample or work around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will get the time duration of video from youtube page.

Example :

```
<div class="ytp-time-display notranslate"><span class="ytp-time-current">0:45</span><span class="ytp-time-separator"> / </span><span class="ytp-time-duration">47:53</span><button class="ytp-live-badge ytp-button" disabled="true">Live</button></div>
```

Exact tag:

```
<span class="ytp-time-duration">47:53</span>
```

Now create a loop which will run till duration of youtube video.

Java code to run the loop till the duration:

[Would like to create a timer in Selenium and do some action until reach a defined period of time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58181535/would-like-to-create-a-timer-in-selenium-and-do-some-action-until-reach-a-define/58182050?noredirect=1#comment102749682_58182050)